# Returning localDescription from RTCPeerConnection

Tags: javascript, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

When I try to return the `localDescription` from the code below, I get a response that does not contains `candidate` parameter under `sdp`, as shown in the screenshot.

Can anyone please help me understand what am I missing here?

Also, I am not using something like `conn.onicecandidate = evt => {}`  on purpose because I directly want to return a value from the function below.

```js
async function getLocalDesc() {
  const conn = new RTCPeerConnection();
  conn.createDataChannel('');
  const offer = await conn.createOffer();
  await conn.setLocalDescription(offer);
  return conn.localDescription;
}

(async () => {
  console.log(await getLocalDesc())
})();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ICE Candidate gathering takes time and you just await setLocalDescription which starts the process. It does not wait for gathering to be complete or any candidates, you'll need to wait for either the `candidate` event or the `gatheringstatechange` event (to a gatheringState of completed) for the SDP to contain the candidates.

https://webrtchacks.com/trickle-ice/ has some details on why that is not a good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

We can return a promise from our function that will provide the required param i.e. `candidate` once it gets resolved.

```js
async function getLocalDesc(){
    const conn = new RTCPeerConnection();
    conn.createDataChannel('');
    const offer =  await conn.createOffer();
    await conn.setLocalDescription(offer);
    return new Promise(resolve =>  conn.onicecandidate = event => resolve(event));
}

(async () => {
  console.log(await getLocalDesc())
})();
```